# Gravityforms field value from another field

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to make a field with Gravity Forms that gets its value(s) from other fields in the same form. Is this possible with merge tags for example?

Reason for this is I'm trying to get a simple list of values from multiple fields that I can store in user_meta (with GF user registration). There are 10+ checkbox fields, where the user can select 1 or all. This new field would serve as a hidden field that gets all the data user has entered (checked) in the checkbox fields. GF user registration accepts only one field as a pointer for the user_meta value so making the logic in that end is a no-go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written a snippet that supports this:

https://gist.github.com/spivurno/7029518

Usage instructions are included in the comments.

Comment: Looks great! I'll give this a try today.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: Add to your theme's functions.php and follow the inline instructions.